# Run purrr::map_dfr on dataframe rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, functional-programming, purrr, furrr

Given a `dataframe`, say `iris` default, how to configure `purrr::map_dfr()` function to run on each row of the `dataframe` and perform function `foo`.

Here is one row of my df, please take into account that value is always a large JSON:

```
structure(list(Key = "2019/01/04/14/kuku@pupu.com_2ed026cb-8e9f-4392-9cc4-9f580b9d3aab_1345a5a4-3d5b-48a0-a678-67ed09a6f487_2019-01-04-14-52-43-537", 
    LastModified = "2019-01-04T14:52:44.000Z", ETag = "\"1c6269ab8b7baa85f0d2567de417f0d0\"", 
    Size = 35280, Owner = "e7c0d260939d15d18866126da3376642e2d4497f18ed762b608ed2307778bdf1", 
    StorageClass = "STANDARD", Bucket = "comp-kukupupu-streamed-data", 
    user_name = "kuku@pupu.com", value = list(---here goes a large json), 
    obs_id = 1137L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

and my function is:

```
extract_scroll_data <- function(df) {

  tryCatch({

    j <- fromJSON(unlist(df$value))

    if (is_empty(fromJSON(j$sensorsData)) | is_empty(fromJSON(j$eventList))) {

      return(tibble())

    } else {

      return(set_names(as_tibble(fromJSON(j$eventList, bigint_as_char = TRUE), 
                                 .name_repair = "unique"), 
                       nm = c("time_stamp", 
                              "x", "y", "size", 
                              "pressure", "scroll", "state")) %>%
               dplyr::mutate("user_name" = df$user_name,
                             "obs_id" = df$obs_id))
    }

  }, warning = function(war) {

    # Warning handler picks up where error was generated:
    print(paste0("Warning: occured at ", df$obs_id, war))

  }, error = function(err) {

    # error handler picks up where error was generated
    print(paste0("Error: occured at ", df$obs_id, err))

  }, finally = {

    gc()

  })

}
```

Please advise why it doesn't use the dataframe rows?

Comment: just `map_dfr(iris, foo)` ? Works with `map_dfr(mtcars, sqrt)` but I think you are looking for something else. Can you explain with details of `foo` and expected output?

Comment: Why not just use apply? apply(dataframe,1,sd)

Comment: Simply don't do that.

Comment: @RonakShah the issue is that my dataframe is huge, and I see unexpected results when I am running on it using the parallel version of purrr, furrr::map_dfr.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for your super helpful comment!

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt I will post the head of the dataframe shortly and the function I use

Comment: If your dataframe is too huge to have work with efficiently there are two options: 1. Work with a flat file instead, and only take a bit into the memory at the time, 2. Use the SparkR package.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt please take a look on my question update

Comment: @RonakShah please take a look on my question update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map_dfr()`, as any other member of `map` family iterates over a list and `data.frame` is really a list of columns. You can check that out with `typeof(iris)` and `as.list(iris)`. To make `map_dfr()` iterate over rows instead, you have to transform your `data.frame` into a list of rows with `split()` function.

```
iris %>%
  split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
  purrr::map_dfr(do_stuff)
```

Comment: What about using: `furrr::future_pmap_dfr(list(data_df$user_name,
                                             data_df$obs_id,
                                             data_df$value),
                                        function(x, y, z) extract_scroll_data(x, y, z))`

Comment: That should do as well

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `extract_scroll_data` function. Are you sure, you adjusted it to accept 3 arguments, and not just `data.frame` as in the question?

Comment: Sure I did. I think the issue is if I am using pmap with a list of 3 vectors it doesn't use  1 element of all 3, then second, then 3rd but all combinations.

Comment: Well, it should. Try this code to learn its behavior: `pmap(list(c('a', 'b', 'c'), c('x', 'y', 'z')), paste)`